# install chessX software in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, chess

I am trying to install this Chess Database utility, but when i extract the file i see no way to compile the code or whatever it needs to execute the software. My question is how i install this software?!

Answer (score 1):

Open "Software Center" and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type "chessX" after that this software found and you can easy install. Just press "Install" button (in top right).

[image]